# Laravel Unterminated comment

Tags: php, laravel, kubernetes, laravel-blade

I am receiving the following error `Unterminated comment starting line 56 (View: /var/www/html/storage/framework/views/1df3d0ed15cec9bc6239326dc532d4c861789455.blade.php)`

When inspecting the file in the pod that caused the exception (application is hosted in kubernetes) the line that its referring to is perfectly fine.

```php
<?php /**PATH /var/www/html/storage/framework/views/1df3d0ed15cec9bc6239326dc532d4c861789455.blade.php ENDPATH**/ ?>
```

Which is added by the blade view compiler to make it easier to debug. I can restart the pod to solve the error but it will come back after a while, to a **different** view then.